# mp3 file uploaded on ftp loads twice in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I have an mp3 file uploaded on my server and when i'm linking to it with Chrome, i get these results in the Network tab of the developer tools:

[image]

It seems like it gets loaded twice.

Also, in the **Console tab** i get the following:

> Resource interpreted as Other but transferred with MIME type undefined.

Could someone explain it to me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If chrome load smth twice, it usually happens if your favicon.ico not found. Chrome looking for /favicon.ico and can load page twice, if your 404 page same as the one you load. Check if icon shows in chrome.

```
<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" sizes="32x32" type="image/png" />
```